# Copy from clipboard to array in VB

Tags: excel, ms-access, outlook, vba

I'm trying to use the split funtion here. I'm trying to get content from the clipboard then store it into an array then populate the subject line with whatever I get from the array. But i always get a type mismatch error. I will appreciate some help. Here's my code

```
Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim myString As String


'Get data from the clipboard.
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

'Get clipboard contents
myString = DataObj.GetText
varArray() = Split(myString, Chr(10))

With OutMail
    .BodyFormat = 3
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .subject = varArray(0) & " - " & varArray(2) & " - " & varArray(4)
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    oRng.collapse 1
    oRng.Paste
    .Display

End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`Dim varArray() As Variant` to `Dim varArray () as String`

also, `varArray = Split(myString, Chr(10))` is fine.

Comment: I tested it and you were half right.  But good enough to get my +1.  If you try and assign an array of string to a variant array (e.g.  `Dim varArray() As Variant : varArray() = Split(myString, Chr(10))`) it throws a `Type Mismatch Error`.  There is no error if you assign a variant array to it(e.g.  varArray() = Array()".  If you try and assign a value to a variant `Dim varArray As Variant` using () it throws a `Script out of range` error.  Of course you can assign an array string to a regular variant with no errors.